# Insert shortcode between '<div>'

Tags: shortcode

I would like to insert a shortcode in the code just after "$cb_post_views" so the shortcode appears on the same line

```
if ( ( $cb_meta_onoff == 'on' ) || ( $cb_posts_on == true ) ) {
        $cb_byline = '<div class="cb-byline">' . $cb_author . $cb_date . $cb_cat_output . $cb_comments . $cb_post_views . '</div>';
    }

    return $cb_byline;
}}
```

I tried many things but I can't find a way out :(

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us? Whay do you want to insert a shortcode in a PHP script? In general, you can think in shortcodes as placeholders for PHP functions that output dinamic content to be used in contexts where PHP functions can not be used directly; within a PHP script there is no reason to use a placeholder, instead, you should use the shortcode's function callback directly (maybe tere are some situations where the callback can not be used directly, but I can not imaging one right now).

Answer (score 2):

just use

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[YOUR_SHORT_CODE_HERE]');?>
```

For more information:

[Short-code in code file](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)

```
$cb_byline = '<div class="cb-byline">' . $cb_author . $cb_date . $cb_cat_output . $cb_comments . $cb_post_views . do_shortcode('[YOUR_SHORT_CODE_HERE]'). '</div>';
}
```

For Plugin "I Recommend This" :

```
<?php if( function_exists('dot_irecommendthis') ) dot_irecommendthis(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the fast response. I already tried that ;) and when I do it, the entire site disappear :(

Comment: What kind of short-code you are using, please share more details.

Comment: If you are making custom theme please add this to functions.php as well:

add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode', 11);

Comment: please read this link for more information 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282987/do-shortcode-not-working

Comment: the shortcode is [dot_recommends] from that very simple plugin [link]https://wordpress.org/plugins/i-recommend-this/[/link]. The theme is a premium theme. 11 ?

Comment: try using <?php if( function_exists('dot_irecommendthis') ) dot_irecommendthis(); ?> in case of this plugin.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that it's not a problem of "do_shortcode not working" because we have 6 other shortcodes working since months

Comment: :( same result : our site disappear.

Comment: Please print your error what the fatal error is ?

In Config file :

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: "syntax error" on line 1006. Which confirms what I think since the begining : find a way to "wrap" the shortcode because of the apostrophe around each <div>

Comment: You have syntax error in your PHP code its not problem of shortcode and for template file you need to use code in this way:

<?php if( function_exists('dot_irecommendthis') ) dot_irecommendthis(); ?> 

You can test using thin in your single.php for each individual post.

Comment: please have look at this link as well:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267992/wordpress-wrap-div-inside-echo-shortcode-php

Comment: I tried the <?php if( function_exists('dot_irecommendthis') ) dot_irecommendthis(); ?> into single.php and it works at the end of the post. I'm going to try the link you put